# Exporting data to csv file in angular typescript

Tags: angular, csv

I am trying to export some data to a CSV file. I have it working in chrome but in IE11 I get redirected to another page with the blob data as the url.

I have filtered data I want to export listed under a class array called *this.filteredReviews*. I have a button that calls *downloadButtonPush* function. I am creating an anchor tag at the end of the body that is hidden and clicks itself after creation to download the csv data.  Below is my code.

```
downloadButtonPush() {
    var csvData = this.ConvertToCSV(this.filteredReviews);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    var blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'ETPHoldReview.csv';
    a.click();
}
ConvertToCSV(objArray: any): string {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    var row = "";

    for (var index in objArray[0]) {
        //Now convert each value to string and comma-separated
        row += index + ',';
    }
    row = row.slice(0, -1);
    //append Label row with line break
    str += row + '\r\n';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','

            line += array[i][index];
        }
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
}
```

In chrome the data exports fine but in IE instead of opening the file download manager, I get redirected to a new page with the following as the URL address.

blob:6F807758-B267-4F51-8B6F-0CFDAFE68B78

Does anyone know why this code isn't working in IE or know if there is an easier way of exporting json to csv in angular?

Comment: This is great, I used it and it's fabulous, thanks GMK and ModestMonk. The only change i made was to replace "navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);" with "alert('Please run this app in chrome');" :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to make a special case for IE (imagine that). It uses the [msSaveBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772331(v=vs.85).aspx) or [msSaveOrOpenBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772332(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Try rewriting your downloadButtonPush() function like this

```
downloadButtonPush() {
  var csvData = this.ConvertToCSV(this.filteredReviews);
  var blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'ETPHoldReview.csv';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

I had the same problem a while ago and took most of this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202301/301379) by PierreDuc

Comment: That was it! Thanks!! I had taken a break, was so frustrated with it lol. Worked like a charm and thanks for the explanation/link.

Comment: @ModestMonk Can u pls help me with this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281848/how-to-save-blob-file-extensions-using-angular2csv-plugin?noredirect=1#comment89546524_51281848

Comment: I did everything same like this answer except this.. const blob = new Blob(data,{ type: 'text/csv', endings: 'native' }); ... here data is string[]

Answer (score 0):

As your last statement says you want easiest way to download the data in csv . I will recommend you to use AngularCsv for export json to csv.

Installation

```
npm install --save angular-csv
```

Example

```
import { AngularCsv } from 'angular-csv/dist/Angular-csv';
 
var data = [
  {
    name: "Test 1",
    age: 13,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    age: 11,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 4',
    age: 10,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
];
 
new AngularCsv(data, 'My Report');
```

One thing you need to understand it have the different name but internal functionality of each package is same and you can use any package in any angular version but i will recommend you if you are using angular2 then use angular2-csv and if you are using angular7 then use angular7-csv.

1. Angular2

```
npm install --save angular2-csv
```

2. Angular 5

```
npm install --save angular5-csv
```

3. Angular 7

```
npm install --save angular7-csv
```

for more information go through https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular7-csv