# How to save blob file extensions using angular2csv plugin

Tags: angular, csv, plugins

I have the code to download my JSON data to csv . I am able to download using windows machine and mac machine. But in iPad device, it comes as a blob file ( blob:https:// ) .  Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Safari has issues with downloading blobs. You can read [here](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv/issues/29) for more information. This can only be fixed if the angular2csv changes their code. I suggest you file a bug report with them :)

Comment: Actually its working fine with Safari browser with mach machine. The problem is when i try to download in iPad device. Not sure why it opens as blob in iPad

Comment: @PierreDuc Do you mean to say that the feature is not supported in iPad safari but supports mac machine safari browser? The link you had provided above doesnt explain about iPad Safari issue. I am desperately waiting for a solution

Comment: Exactly. The main issue is that ios safari does not support the [download attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download), which is used in the [angular2csv here](https://github.com/javiertelioz/angular2-csv/blob/master/Angular2-csv.ts#L101). Here you can read more about this annoying [issue](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/12). *start rant* I don't get it how apple keeps getting away with being so stubborn *end rant*